# Your method must return a value. If your method has multiple paths of execution

Tags: java, if-statement

Write a method named season that takes two integers as parameters representing a month and day and that returns a String indicating the season for that month and day. Assume that months are specified as an integer between 1 and 12 (1 for January, 2 for February, and so on) and that the day of the month is a number between 1 and 31.

If the date falls between 12/16 and 3/15, you should return "Winter". If the date falls between 3/16 and 6/15, you should return "Spring". If the date falls between 6/16 and 9/15, you should return "Summer". And if the date falls between 9/16 and 12/15, you should return "Fall".

***This is my code***

```
public static String season (int month, int day){
if (month>9 && month<12){
    if (month==9 && day>=16 || month==12 && day<=15){
        return "Fall";
    }
}else if (month>6 && month<9){
    if (month==6 && day>=16 || month==9 && day<=15){
        return "Summer";
    }
}else if(month>3 && month<6){
    if (month==3 && day>=16 || month==6 && day<=15){
        return "Sprint";
    }
}else {
    return "Winter";
}
}
```

***This is error***
    Line 17
    Your method must return a value. If your method has multiple paths of execution (such as if/else statements), every path must contain a return statement. Also beware of nested if/else statements that end with an 'else if'.
    missing return statement
    } ^ 1 error 21 warnings

Comment: What does this return on 16th of september?

Answer (score 2):

your inner if cases have no else and the inner if will never match. For example what happens on 01.Sep?
In that case your function does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value in every circumstances.. so just add a return at the end of the method. Based on your code, if the month is 9 and the day is 15 it will fail to return a result.

```
public static String season (int month, int day){
if (month>9 && month<12){
    if (month==9 && day>=16 || month==12 && day<=15){
        return "Fall";
    }
}else if (month>6 && month<9){
    if (month==6 && day>=16 || month==9 && day<=15){
        return "Summer";
    }
}else if(month>3 && month<6){
    if (month==3 && day>=16 || month==6 && day<=15){
        return "Sprint";
    }
}else {
    return "Winter";
}

return "";
}
```

Comment: It would be even better to help OP to achieve the higher goal of returning a **correct** value.

Comment: I'm just answering the problem posted by OP. The correct value is out of context here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a value in all execution paths or throw exception.

```
public static String season(int month, int day)
{
    if (month > 9 && month < 12)
    {
        if (month == 9 && day >= 16 || month == 12 && day <= 15)
        {
            return "Fall";
        }
    }
    else if (month > 6 && month < 9)
    {
        if (month == 6 && day >= 16 || month == 9 && day <= 15)
        {
            return "Summer";
        }
    }
    else if (month > 3 && month < 6)
    {
        if (month == 3 && day >= 16 || month == 6 && day <= 15)
        {
            return "Sprint";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "Winter";
    }

    throw new InvalidParameterException("no matching season found");
}
```

Comment: -1 for just replicating the faulty logic? Do you really think you make a faulty program any better by throwing a throws statement at the end?

Comment: actually that is not the question here. i am just trying to provide specific answer to a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String season(int month, int day){

        if (month==9 && day>=16 || month==12 && day<=15||month==10||month==11){
            return "Fall";
        }   else if (month==6 && day>=16 || month==9 && day<=15||month==7||month==8){
            return "Summer";
        } else    if (month==3 && day>=16 || month==6 && day<=15||month==4||month==5){
            return "Spring";
        } else {
        return "Winter";
    }
}
```

Comment: A wall of code is seldom a good answer. Consider editing your question to include an explanation of the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return ""` before and of your function. So if you function `season` returns empty string it means you have bad parameters or other error.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a string variable. Depending upon the if condition, assign the value to this string variable.
Return this string variable at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to program this way:

```
if (before march 16 || after dec 15) return "Winter";
if (before june 16)  return "Spring";   // since we're not before march 16!!
...
```

With every if statement you eliminate 1 case and do not check conditions multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if (month==9 && day>=16 || month>9 && month<12 || month==12 && day<=15) {
    return "Fall";
}
else if (month==6 && day>=16 || month>6 && month<9 || month==9 && day<=15) {
    return "Summer";
}
else if (month==3 && day>=16 || month>3 && month<6 || month==6 && day<=15) {
    return "Sprint";
}
else {
    return "Winter";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try below code

```
    public static String season(int month, int day) {
if (month > 9 && month < 12) {
    if (month == 9 && day >= 16 || month == 12 && day <= 15 || !(month == 9 || month == 12)) {
        return "Fall";
    }
} else if (month > 6 && month < 9) {
    if (month == 6 && day >= 16 || month == 9 && day <= 15 || !(month == 6 || month == 9)) {
        return "Summer";
    }
} else if (month > 3 && month < 6) {
    if (month == 3 && day >= 16 || month == 6 && day <= 15 || !(month == 3 || month == 6)) {
        return "Sprint";
    }
} else {
    return "Winter";
}



 }
```

Comment: It would really be better if you showed OP why his code is wrong. And, btw, did you try to compile this?